# How to call onActivityResult for fragment

Tags: java, android

I have this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PaymentActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, paypal.REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
```

override function call onActivityResult but it call the result.

Comment: have you tried override `onActivityResult` in `FragmentActivity`?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, paypal.REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);

This calls onActivityResult in the activity

Instead use the method in fragment

startActivityForResult(intent, paypal.REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);

Answer (score 1):

If you call `startActivityForResult` from the `Fragment` the result will deliver to the `Fragment`. And if you call `startActivityForResult` from the `Activity` the result will deliver to the `Activity`. When `Fragment` calls `StartActivityForResult` the `requestCode` will be changed by the `Activity`, so it will know how to deliver the result to which `Fragment`.

In your case you should change line:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, paypal.REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
```

to:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, paypal.REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
```

Comment: I'm also use both methods

Answer (score 0):

Where do you override the onActivityForResult method?.

If the answer is in your FragmentActivity.
You should use: getActivity().startActivityForResult

If the answer is in your Fragment.
You should use: startActivityForResult.